# Vue, why curly braces message data doesn't show up?

Tags: vue.js

below is my html, please help me have a look.
the first section is using curly brace, I want show the data, but it fails
the second section is using v-text or v-html, it works fine, why? 
and how can I show the first one also. thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app-1">
<p>{{message}}</p>
</div>
<div id="app-2">
<p v-text='message'></p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
const app1 = new Vue({
 el:'#app-1',
 data: {
 message: 'Hello app-1!'
 }
})
const app2 = new Vue({
 el: '#app-2',
 data: {
 message: 'Hello app-2!'
}
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems code is alright and both sections work on my end, please refresh and retry.

Comment: works fine https://jsbin.com/coriwexoza/edit?html,output

Comment: sorry, I am in the jekyll!! how can I escape for render {{}}?